# Kafka multi node cluster monitoring

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I have Kafka cluster wkth 3 server and 3 broker each. I already able to monitor 1 broker using jmx. But I noticed data tranfered by jmx is only related to specified broker to which we connect.

How can I monitor "cluster"in general (e.g. I want to know a messages-in-throughput of a topic)?

Comment: Can you share the code? other than that if you are asking monitoring clusters, in general, using Kafka then -- There are some [Open Source Monitoring tools](https://sematext.com/blog/kafka-open-source-monitoring-tools/)   **OR** using [performance metrics](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-kafka-performance-metrics/) **OR** [this](https://blog.serverdensity.com/how-to-monitor-kafka/) might be helpful for you.

Comment: I dont have any code. I am using default kafka monitoring port and use JConsole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single brokers JMX data won't know about other brokers. You'd have to install metrics collectors on each server and aggregate the data into a metrics database.

Prometheus + JMX exporter + Grafana is a popular combination. Then PromQL would be responsible for querying data over each host.